# How to swap to the other hands on bought rigged?

Tags: mesh, armature, pose-mode

Just bought a pre-created mesh to play around with posing a humanoid, it seems to come with additional hands? How do I swap to the other hands?

[image]

Comment: I doubt anyone will be able to help you with the limited information you provided.  The rigged mesh author should have provided documentation.  Are there any mesh custom properties for this swapping?

Comment: Have you checked if the have vertex groups and weights? If yes, you should be able to move them into position and parent the armature to them *With Empty Groups* (Ctrl+P). The closed fists will probably not work that way because the rest pose of the armature is different, I guess.